# Makefile for static library with self-test capability

Tags: c, makefile

I want to have Makefile for my static library where I can conditionally build it as program to perform simple self-test. My current Makefille looks like follows:

```
OBJECTS = sm3.o ./core/sm3_internal.o
INCLUDES = -I. -I./core
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -O3
CC = c99

OUT = libsm3.a

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES)

$(OUT): $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJECTS)
```

At my main library file I have:

```
#ifdef TEST
main(int argc, int* argv[])
{
  //my self-test logic here
}
#endif
```

Where should I add -DTEST flag? If I add it to CFLAGS and then add line:

```
test: $(OBJECTS)
```

library also would be build with main, which obviously is not something I want.

Comment: Why not put the test program in a separate source file?

Comment: @immibis no particular reason, it appeared to be good idea to validate library this way

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you compile `main.c` conditionally instead:

```
$(TESTOUT): $(OBJECTS) $(TESTOBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: first suggestion produces library, modified it a little (replaced OUT with OBJECTS and test with sm3 - is naming needs to match?) and I've got working executable with my test but there are following problems: 1) if I build test first then when using library I'm getting duplicate main function, and if I build library first my test build fails with error `undefined reference to WinMain` (I'm using cygwin)

Comment: Ye, the old object file didn't change, so it doesn't matter what you define. You could get around it by deleting the object file, but I guess you should do it properly with two separate targets instead. I'll remove the first suggestion.